# How to update a line from txt file depends on a condition?

Tags: struct, text-files

i have a problem in my code i tried many things but i could not solved.
The problem is i am codding a stock managment program(It is not about SQL or whatever comes to your mind), just a basic consol app for a school project.

My code is creating a product depends on a struct and then write on a file which one is called "database.txt".

Assume, a personel wants to change details of item according to its referance number(referance number defined like REF:)

When read the database file if the referance number founds i want to changes all line untill the next referance number. But when i try to change somethig went wrong like picture.
[Before Updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNINT.png)[After Updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMG1N.png)

```
if(button2 == 2)
            {

                string refNo;
                string word;
                cout <<"Enter the referance number of item for update" << endl;
                cin >> refNo;
                refNo = "REF:"+refNo;
                fstream file(databaseFile.c_str());
                if(file.is_open())
                {
                    while(getline(file, word))
                    {
                        if(word == refNo)
                        {
                        product entity = createItem(true);
                        file << entity.detail.category << endl;
                        file << entity.name << endl;
                        file << entity.price << endl;
                        file << entity.profitMargine << endl;
                        file << entity.stock << endl;
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Completely Rewrite the entire file*

1. Create a new file.
2. Copy the original file to the new file up to the start of your desire line you want to change (here the user's Ref:)
3. Write the new line in new file
4. Copy the remaining parts of original file to the new file
5. Close both original and new files. Delete the original file, and    rename the new file

Comment: But if a personel wants to change again any product i need to create new file again thus everytime the file name should be changed ? How is it implement to code ?

Comment: Yes, actually you rename the newly created file to the old file. Interesting to know that this an example of how deal with file in c++; means that, in real world scenario, a DBMS is used for CRUD operations.